# How to iterate over two Boost Preprocessor sequences at the same time?

Tags: c++, c, boost, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I was wondering if the following can be done via Boost Preprocessor sequences. (Most of the SO questions as well as Boost Preprocessor examples talk about only 1 sequence)

```
#define seq1 (a)(b)(c)
#define seq2 (1)(2)(3)

// Now iterate over both of them at the same time
```

Here is my motivation. I have to define few functions for a lot of types e.g.

```
void add(int val) { obj.AddInt(val); }
void add(double val) { obj.AddDouble(val); }
```

I was thinking of defining two sequences like

```
#define types (int)(double)...
#define funcs (AddInt)(AddDouble)...
```

and then write a macro for the function add, and iterate over the two sequences.

Comment: Why not a single sequence of tuples? E.g. `((int, AddInt), (double, AddDouble))`...

Comment: I actually have 3-4 sequences and I have read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475453/how-to-use-boostpreprocessor-to-unzip-a-sequence

I guess this potentially can be done, but was wondering if there is a way for iterating over multiple sequences because those macros sequences are already defined.

Comment: A quick search shows me there's a library out there with a zip macro: https://github.com/mcinglis/libpp/blob/master/zip.h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each_i.html) and [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_elem.html) to do it as follows:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>

#define types (int)(double)
#define funcs (AddInt)(AddDouble)

#define MACRO(_,funcs,i,type) \
    void add(type val) { obj.BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(i, funcs)(val); }

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(MACRO, funcs, types)
```

The `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` macro iterates over the sequence `types`, applying `MACRO` to each element. The second argument to `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` is passed as the second argument to each invocation of `MACRO`, and `i` denotes the zero-based index of the current element being iterated over. Therefore, when `MACRO` is being expanded, `type` is the `i`-th element of `types` and `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(i, funcs)` is the `i`-th element of `funcs`.

For a more general solution, you can do something like:

```
#define ITERATE_OVER_TWO_SEQ_(_,data,i,e2) \
   BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,data)(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(i, BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1,data)), e2)
#define ITERATE_OVER_TWO_SEQ(macro, s1, s2) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(ITERATE_OVER_TWO_SEQ_, (macro)(s1), s2)
```

and use it as follows:

```
#define MACRO(type,func) void add(type val) { obj.func(val); }
ITERATE_OVER_TWO_SEQ(MACRO, types, funcs)
```

An even more generic way would be to use `SEQ_ZIP` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987223/3919155), `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` and `BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM`. For example:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#define MACRO(_,d,seq) \
    void add(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,seq) val) \
    { obj.BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, seq)(val); }

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, _, SEQ_ZIP((types)(funcs))
```