# How to zip multiple Boost Preprocessor sequences?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

Given multiple Boost Preprocessor sequences:

```
#define S1 (a)(b)(c)
#define S2 (1)(2)(3)
#define S3 (x1)(x2)(x3)
```

How do I zip them using the preprocessor so the end result would be `((a)(1)(x1))((b)(2)(x2))((c)(3)(x3))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `SEQ_ZIP` macro for this purpose as follows:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/expr_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/size.hpp>

#define SEQ_ZIP_NTH_(_,d,e) (BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(d, e))
#define SEQ_ZIP_NTHS_(_,i,ss) (BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(SEQ_ZIP_NTH_,i,ss))
#define SEQ_ZIP_2(ne,ss) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(ne, SEQ_ZIP_NTHS_, ss)
#define SEQ_ZIP_(ne,ss) BOOST_PP_EXPR_IF(ne, SEQ_ZIP_2(ne, ss))
#define SEQ_ZIP(ss) SEQ_ZIP_(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,ss)), ss)
```

And use it to zip your sequences like this:

```
#define S1 (a)(b)(c)
#define S2 (1)(2)(3)
#define S3 (x1)(x2)(x3)
SEQ_ZIP((S1)(S2)(S3))
```